# Ffmpeg line break with right side alignment

Tags: ffmpeg, right-to-left, linebreaks

i use this ffmpeg command to render a video from images - the problem is when i use carriage /n i can’t make right side alignment for Arabic text, i can’t use multiple drawtext for this because text is from database.

```
ffmpeg -r:v 1/5 -f concat -safe 0 -i /system/gobro.txt -i "/system/chill.mp3" -vf "scale=iw*min(1280/iw\,800/ih):ih*min(1280/iw\,800/ih), pad=1280:800:(1280-iw*min(1280/iw\,800/ih))/2:(800-ih*min(1280/iw\,800/ih))/2,
drawbox=enable='between(t,5,39.9)':y=(ih-110):color=black@0.9:width=iw:height=110:t=filldrawtext=enable='between(t,10,14.9)':fontfile=/ttf/changa-medium.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w-20):y=(h-text_h-60):text='غير كانت الخطّة ', 
drawtext=enable='between(t,10,14.9)':fontfile=/TTF/Changa-Medium.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w-20):y=(h-text_h-15):text='gfuishg isfdhgi usfdhgi sfdg /n hello this is new line'" 
-c:a aac -shortest -y -pix_fmt yuv420p /public/video.mp4 2> /system/out.txt
```

[screen shot explain the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RWcx.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: I think your sample code is missing a comma between the value "fill" and the filter name "drawtext" in this sequence "t=filldrawtext".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it matters whether your text is a right-to-left script or a left-to-right script. I think the only issue you need to solve is the *alignment* or the *justification* of the text. In your sample photo, it seems that you want all text to be right-justified whether it is written in an RTL or LTR script. If I am correct, then something similar to the following should do what you want.

In your sample code, you put the LTR text into one filter

```
drawtext=enable='between(t,10,14.9)':fontfile=/TTF/Changa-Medium.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w-20):y=(h-text_h-15):text='gfuishg isfdhgi usfdhgi sfdg /n hello this is new line'
```

Separate the two lines into two drawtext filters, and "align" the two strings on the right.

```
drawtext=enable='between(t,10,14.9)':fontfile=/TTF/Changa-Medium.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w-20):y=(h-text_h-15):text='gfuishg isfdhgi usfdhgi sfdg',
drawtext=enable='between(t,10,14.9)':fontfile=/TTF/Changa-Medium.ttf:fontsize=20:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w-20):y=(h-text_h-line_h-15):text='hello this is new line'
```

For the second line of text, I changed the value of the y offset. I added the term "-line_h" so the second line should be below the first line.